# Associating multiple items with a single REST call

Tags: loopbackjs

I am using the Loopback framework, and have modelA which is in a many-to-many relation with modelB.
I want to know if it's possible to relate multiple items from modelB to modelA.
There is currently a way to relate one item with this call:

```
/modelA/{id}/modelB/rel/{fk}
```

Is there any way to perform this in a bulk operation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can simply do it through a filter. ModelA has many modelBs, Let me assume the relation name is 'modelBs'

```
modelA.find({
    where: [your filter option on model A]
    include: {
        relation: 'modelBs',
        scope: {
            [your filters on model B]
        }
    }
})
```

in restful way:

```
/modelAs?filter[include]=modelBs&filter[where]....
```

The official documentation may help: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data

Comment: I actually want to add records to the modelAmodelBs linking table. I found some example that goes like this: `modelA.modelBs.add(modelAObj, function(err) {});` , but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be [HasManyThrough model](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations).

I believe your model names starts with lowercase but ideally it should be `ModelA` and `ModelB` and their instances can then be saved in `modelA` and `modelB` variables.

In order to use `add` method, you will need to first find instance of `ModelA` first using `ModelA.findById` which you can save in `modelA` variable and then use the following code:

```
modelA.modelBs.add(modelBFieldsObject, function(err, patient) {
  ...
});
```

where modelBs should be the name of relation in the `ModalA.json` file as in

```
"relations": {
    "modelBs": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ModelB",
      "foreignKey": "modelAId",
      "through": "ModelAModelB",
      "keyThrough": "modelBId"
    }
    ...
```

I think it should be allowed to pass an array of `modelBFieldsObject` to create multiple instances as in

```
modelA.modelBs.add([modelBFieldsObject, modelBFieldsObject], function(err, patient) {
  ...
});
```

**Tip:** For clarity, name your models beginning with upper case letter and their instance variable in `camelCase` format.

**References:** [Methods added to the model](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations#HasManyThroughrelations-Methodsaddedtothemodel).